# EXCEL: If a cell in a sheet matches a cell in another Sheet, print the cell to the right

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I need help with Excel. I have an excel spreadsheet with 2 sheets.

Sheet1 column A contains 4,000 employee numbers
Sheet2 column A contains 10,000 employee numbers
Sheet2 column B contains 10,000 employee emails

Using the employee numbers in Sheet 1 as a "key", I need to find a way to search Sheet2 and print the email from Sheet2 column B to Sheet1 column B. The first 3 employee numbers are the same on each sheet, but then it jumps to a random number in the list of 10,000.

I tried using this but I keep getting #N/A

`=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(Sheet2!B1,Sheet2!A:A,0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))
```

Should Find the e-mail in Sheet 2, Column `B` that matches the employee number in Sheet 1, column `A`